# Build a Loop Using Javascript Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, json, twitter-bootstrap, for-loop, html-lists

Getting a bit stuck on this, have a got a list of items from an json file. The problem is I want to separate the file in ul li of ten. rather than having a long list of li. I want to separate them into to bootstrap columns of 3 for example col-lg-4, needs to be in javascript and not in query.

This is what I've got so far:

```
function buildCountryList(countryData) {
    var countryName = null;
    var countryURL = null;

    var countryListContainer = document.getElementById('countryList');
    var countryList = document.createElement("ul");
    var countryListItem = document.createElement("li");
    var countryLink = document.createElement("a");

    countryLoaded = true;

    for (var i = 0; i < countryData.countryList.length; i++) { 

        countryName = countryData.countryList[i].country;
        countryURL = countryData.countryList[i].url;
        countryLink.href = countryURL;
        countryLink.innerHTML = countryName;

        // countryListItem.appendChild(countryLink);
        // countryList.appendChild(countryListItem);
        // countryListContainer.appendChild(countryList);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice you need create a new `<li>` element **inside the loop** by `var`. Other wise it's just going to be overwrite each other.

Here is a working demo of what I believe you wanted : http://jsfiddle.net/kP5zX/1/

basicly just fix the error I mentioned and use `.className` to add bootstrap class names.